# Typeahead.js: how does footer query work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, handlebars.js, typeahead.js

I am using [Twitter typeahead.js](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js). The docs say:

> footer– Rendered at the bottom of the dataset. Can be either a HTML
>   string or a precompiled template. If it's a precompiled template, the
>   passed in context will contain query and isEmpty.

However, I cannot manage to use `query`.

I would like to use it in something like:

```
footer: Handlebars.compile('<h3 class="tt-footer"><a href="search/%query"> See more results</a></h3>')
```

How does it actually work??

Comment: Is that the correct syntax for Handlebars? Seems like it would be `{{query}}`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An example of a footer in action can be seen here:

http://jsfiddle.net/Fresh/d7jdp03d/

Do a search for a movie (e.g. Aliens) and you'll see the footer at the bottom of the suggestions.

The key part of the code is:

```
footer: Handlebars.compile("<b>Searched for '{{query}}'</b>")
```

You need to use the [Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/) syntax (i.e. braces) to reference the query value, as this is the templating engine being used in this example.